# Counting red lines from lines of random colors

Tags: python, random, count, turtle-graphics

So if I had a list of colors:

`colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']`

And I used them to randomly color lines. Is it possible to count how many red lines there are altogether? I know it would be easier to count if each line had a fixed color but how would I count if they don't?

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
def lines(xcoord, ycoord):
    import random
    global colors
    penup()  
    goto(xcoord, ycoord)  
    pensize(3)  
    pendown()  
    color(random.choice(colors))  
    forward(100)  
    right(randint(0,360))
    penup()
for _ in range(3):
    lines(randint(min_xcoord, max_xcoord), \
        randint(min_ycoord, max_ycoord))
```

So I want to find how many red lines there are altogether after it finishes drawing, let say 3 lines.

Comment: Can you show your code for drawing the circles?

Comment: I changed my code to draw lines instead of circles because it was easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a code similar to this:

```
from turtle import *
from random import choice
accuracy=64
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
dist=400/accuracy
turn=360/accuracy
color_times = dict(zip(colors, [0, 0, 0])) # {'red':0, 'blue':0', 'green':0}
for j in range(5):
    my_color = choice(colors)
    color(my_color)
    color_times[my_color] += 1
    down()
    for i in range(0,360,turn):
        fd(dist)
        left(turn)
    up()
    fd(25)
mainloop()
print '{}:{}\n {}:{}\n {}:{}'.format('red', color_times['red'], 'blue', color_times['blue', 'green', color_times['green'])
```

Based on your line code:

Change `color(random.choice(colors))` to:

```
my_color = random.choice(colors)
color(my_color)
color_times[my_color] += 1 # you have to initialize color_times before the loop
```

Comment: The right idea, but also consider making use of `collections.Counter`.

Comment: I added bits of the code to mine but then I realised I can't put it into my function because every time it draws a line it will count and then reset when it draws the next line. So does that mean I have to use the counter somewhere else or can I use the counter in my function? Sorry I'm still new to python.

Comment: @user2270501 Oh yeah, sorry; `left(turn)` should be indented under the `for` loop (I changed the code above).

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND Oh awesome it worked! But how do I put the counter in my line function because it doesn't count how many red lines there are altogether just the line that it draws.

Answer (score -1):

first way:
you can create a array list and insert & remove color in it where assigned and then when you want to count just count the red fields of array,

second way:
create array list(key,value) with and insert colors you use in the array keys and put count of each color in value

```
colors[
        red=>0,
        blue=>0,
        green=>0
      ]
```

i hope that helpful.